# How do I implement a POC with spring,apache cxf,maven and integrate with servicemix 7.0.1

Tags: rest, cxf, apache-servicemix

I am new to service mix and any guidance is appreciated.

I am trying to build a restful web service with Apache cxf and deploy it on service mix.

Comment: Welcome! This question, unfortunately, is way too broad to be answerable in Stack Overflow. May I suggest looking at the getting started documentation for the projects you mention?

Comment: hello,I have tried looking into documentation part but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Well then it seems you didn't find the correct documentation because there are plenty 
http://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-apache-cxf

http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/7-Simple-REST-Web-Service-in-Java-with-Spring-and-CXF.html